# stacking multiple columns in one, excel

Tags: excel, stack

I have multiple sheets in one file from different data sources.
I would like to stack data from column A from each sheet into one column.
No empty lines, no other difficulties. 
I can use notepad but I prefer solution inside excel.

i have seen solution for similar problems but they were a bit different and it think is simpler version and could have simpler solution (which will be easy to implement)

I would be grateful for help.
Michal

Answer (score 0):

This is the code adapted for the task you need, you just need to create a new sheet called "output" or change this part of the code for a name you desire

```
Sub stackColumns()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim recipe As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set recipe = wb.Worksheets("output")
    recipe.Range("A:C").ClearContents
    recipe.Cells(1, 1).Value = "stacked A-category"
    recipe.Cells(1, 2).Value = "stacked C-category"

    For Each w In wb.Sheets
        If w.Name <> recipe.Name Then
            For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.Max(w.Cells(w.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, w.Cells(w.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
                recipe.Cells(recipe.Cells(recipe.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Value = w.Cells(i, 1).Value
                recipe.Cells(recipe.Cells(recipe.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Value = w.Cells(i, 3).Value
            Next i
        End If
    Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. I never worked with this kind of codes. Could you recommend an on line training that would help me with to work with it?

Comment: Look, I don't know a good training for basics because I'm from brazil and for learning I used portuguese tutorials, but to use this code you need to go to the Developer tab in the ribbon (if it's not visible you need to set to visible in File ribbon -> options), then enter VBA, click Insert -> new Module, paste the code in the white page that will show up and execute using F5 or the "play" button that you will see in the ribbon... but first you'll need to adjust the code, which I can help if you post a screen of your workbook or upload an example in excel online and let me view it

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AorB8GsfygEpaTsET_TBXzf9uzU  so in this example i want to stack data from column A  (also from column C - my final goal is to find how many times a cobination A&"-"&C exists which is done by countif but I have this solved) so i just need to stack the columns A and C and everything will work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: take a look again, i adapted the code to your sheet, you just need to create an output one